# Creating a C# DLL add-in for Excel without converting VBA code

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

I have created a few rather useful VBA code which I would like to protect. 
Unfortunately Microsoft Office VBA project security is horrible and way too easy to break (otherwise it would have worked!), and to increase security I am thinking of using a C# add-in instead.

I have read some stuff about porting VBA code to C#/VB.NET, and I don't like it because it is extremely cumbersome!

What I'm thinking of is a poor man's solution to secure VBA code.

1) Save VBA code to some text file and encrypt it with some strong encryption.
2) When the user wants to run the code, the C# Add-in will decrypt the VBA code and inject it into the spreadsheet
3) After the code has finished running, the VBA code is deleted so it is not accessible

Hopefully this would make things really simple.

Has anyone tried something like this before?

Comment: There are 3rd party products available which can set VBA code into Excel, e.g. [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells.Vba.VbaModule+Class). However, it is also very easy to disassemble a .NET program back to source-code, so a bad guy will simply read the .NET code and thus will have access to your VBA code

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://www.spreadsheet1.com/move-excel-vba-projects-from-one-workbook-to-another.html

Comment: that unviewable+ seems to be perfect for my use! Rory have you tested it and how did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some ideas.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting

This runs vbscripts in an exe. You can connect to the excel sheet from external rather than vba internal.